# How to do automated Webapplication testing using VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, nunit, watin

Currently I am doing automation testing of webapplications using nunit, watin. How can I achieve same reults using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current automated system test setup for a VS 2010 web app uses NUnit, the CassiniDev development server (http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) and WatiN.  I use ReSharper (plus dotCover) (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ and http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) to run/debug/cover the tests from within VS 2010.

In the NUnit test fixture setup I start the CassiniDev server pointing at the web app directory.  WatiN is then able to test the site by hitting the development server.